# gii does not work with yiiexcel

Tags: php, plugins, yii, centos

I am using Yii and have a plugin YiiExcel. when this plugin is loaded the  Gii does not work. My `index.php`

```
//do not run app before register YiiExcel autoload
$app = Yii::createWebApplication($config);

Yii::import('ext.yiiexcel.YiiExcel', true);
Yii::registerAutoloader(array('YiiExcel', 'autoload'), true);

// Optional:
//  As we always try to run the autoloader before anything else, we can use it to do a few
//      simple checks and initialisations
PHPExcel_Shared_ZipStreamWrapper::register();

if (ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & 2) {
    throw new Exception('Multibyte function overloading in PHP must be disabled for string functions (2).');
}
PHPExcel_Shared_String::buildCharacterSets();

//Now you can run application
$app->run();
```

When I try to generate a file i get

```
PHP Error [2]

require_once(Text/Diff.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory (/opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/gii/components/TextDiff.php:6)

#0 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/gii/components/TextDiff.php(6): CWebApplication->handleError()
#1 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/gii/components/TextDiff.php(6): require_once()
#2 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/YiiBase.php(401): include()
#3 unknown(0): autoload()
#4 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/gii/CCodeGenerator.php(109): spl_autoload_call()
#5 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): ModelGenerator->actionDiff()
#6 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams()
#7 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CController.php(286): ModelGenerator->runAction()
#8 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CController.php(265): ModelGenerator->runActionWithFilters()
#9 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): ModelGenerator->run()
#10 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController()
#11 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#12 /opt/paradox/index.php(31): CWebApplication->run()



[root@portal-test paradox]# ll /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/gii/components/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Nov 27 16:59 Pear
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  537 Aug 12 01:15 TextDiff.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  552 Aug 12 01:15 UserIdentity.php
[root@portal-test paradox]# ll /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/gii/components/Pear/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Aug 12 01:15 Text
[root@portal-test paradox]# ll /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/gii/components/Pear/Text/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 4 apache apache  4096 Nov 27 16:59 Diff
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  7457 Aug 12 01:15 Diff3.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 12044 Aug 12 01:15 Diff.php
[root@portal-test paradox]# ll /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/gii/components/Pear/Text/Diff
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Nov 27 16:59 Engine
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 2188 Aug 12 01:15 Mapped.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Nov 27 16:59 Renderer
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 6785 Aug 12 01:15 Renderer.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 7560 Aug 12 01:15 ThreeWay.php
[root@portal-test paradox]#
```

Comment: it seems this file is missing or misplaced. Text/Diff.php can you include the full path to Text/Diff.php and see i.e (fullpath/Text/Diff.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a file missing. can you please download the **Text/Diff.php** here:

https://www.assembla.com/code/novmir/subversion/nodes/yii/framework/gii/components/Pear/Text/Diff.php?rev=2

and then place it inside the **framework/gii/components/** or **protected/components** folder. it should work.